# Fast S3 operations with AWS JavaScript SDK and agent=false

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to perform thousands of operations in S3 as rapidly as possible.  I have created a Node.js application that will attempt up to 500 operations at a time with the S3 SDK.  Example operations are `s3.copyObject()`, `s3.listObjects`, etc.

In my testing, I found that only a few requests were actually occurring over the wire simultaneously because the agent sees that it's on the same host, and shoves all the requests down the same TCP connection.  I've gotten around it by disabling the agent:

```
AWS.config.httpOptions.agent = false;
```

However to do this I also had to disable SSL:

```
AWS.config.sslEnabled = false;
```

The SDK docs say that a special agent is used for SSL operations.

How can I override the agent for SSL behavior, disabling keep-alive or at least enabling ~500 keep-alive simultaneous connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I hadn't upgraded my copy of Node to v0.12 so I had to set the global agent maxSockets.  Cranking that up took care of this problem.  So did upgrading to Node.js v0.12.02 for the same reason.